# The triangular encoding

Tags: mathematics, cipher

You find a piece of paper. It reads

```
SGJAKFBWJMWQAMZEJJXNFZFPFFVL
```

Can you de-code it?
You will have to add in the spaces. It is a phrase not a word.

Seeing as this is incredibly hard, I will give you a few hints...

> A special triangle is required to do this

And:

> A number line will help

Also:

> Odds and evens are *so, so* different ;)

And the final clue is the title mixed with the tag

I will be *very* impressed by anyone who can even get close on this one...

Comment: If this is too hard I'll add another hint, just ask

Comment: What's the point of posting a puzzle that you're confident no one will be able to solve?  If it isn't solvable without continually adding hints, it's not a good puzzle.  Making it "hard" via insufficient information isn't a hard puzzle, it's an incomplete puzzle.

Comment: When you mention needing a "special triangle" to decode this, the first thing that comes to mind is a Ouija board.

Comment: No, I'll give this as a freebie. It's pascal's

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I am confident someone will decode this it is just a matter of logic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that the solution is:

> Count on a number line, and multiply by -1 if the $n$-th number in Pascal's triangle is even, i.e. the map:
>
>  $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2  & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & -5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & -12 & -13 & -14* & 15 \\ \hline \end{array}$$
>  $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline 1  & 5  & 10  & 10  & 5  & 1  & 1  & 6   & 15 & 20  & 15 & 6   & 1  \\ \hline  16 & 17 & -18 & -19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & -23 & 24 & -25 & 26 & -27 & 28 \\ \hline \end{array}$$
>
>  `*` marking a potential mistake in encoding?

"Alter" each letter appropriately using the second row of the map, and you get

> `TIMEFLIESWHENX*OUAREHAVINGFUN`
>
>  Where "alter" means shift modulo 26, e.g.,
>  1st letter: S + 1 = T
>  2nd letter: G + 2 = I
>  5th letter: K - 5 = F
>  8th letter: W + 8 = E
>  27th letter: V - 27 = U
>
>  In Python this could be:
>  `lambda x,y: chr( ((ord(x) - ord('A') + y) % 26) + ord('A') )`
>
>  Note that the asterisk on the -14 above indicates the real shift should be -13 instead, giving a Y instead of an X

and thus my final answer is the phrase

> Time flies when you are having fun

Comment: Really well done!

Comment: Ah, not only are you correct you have also indeed found an error, I will change it in my question